# InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId .. The same schemaId is already used for type

Tags: c#, swagger, odata, asp.net-core-3.1

I receive the following error.

```
InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId "$Registration" for type "$PortalService.Models.Registration". The same schemaId is already used for type "$PortalService.Models.Registration"
```

I have tried the suggestions in the following link without any succcess.

[swagger error: Conflicting schemaIds: Duplicate schemaIds detected for types A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071513/swagger-error-conflicting-schemaids-duplicate-schemaids-detected-for-types-a-a)

I only have one Registration class in models.  I have tried renaming the class without success.

I am using an OData .Net Core 3.1 project.

Configure Swagger is below

```
 services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n 
                      Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                      \r\n\r\nExample: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                  {
                    {
                      new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                      {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                          {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                          },
                          Scheme = "oauth2",
                          Name = "Bearer",
                          In = ParameterLocation.Header,

                        },
                        new List<string>()
                      }
                    });
            });
```

Use Swagger is below

```
  app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                //c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.BasePath = basepath);

                 
                c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => {
                    Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiPaths paths = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiPaths();
                    foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
                    {
                        paths.Add(path.Key.Replace(path.Key, basepath + path.Key), path.Value);
                    }
                    swaggerDoc.Paths = paths;
                });
            });
            app.UseSwaggerUI(
                options =>
                {
                    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

                    // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version

                    foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                    {
                        options.SwaggerEndpoint($"{basepath}/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                    }

                });
```

This appears to be related to

[Swagger crashes with circular model references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705270/swagger-crashes-with-circular-model-references?rq=1)

I have found that if I comment out the partner back reference from registration, the error goes away but I need this reference.  I am not clear how to fix the situation.

```
[ForeignKey("Partner")]
[DataMember(Name = "PartnerOID")]
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(100)")]
public string PartnerOID { get; set; }
//public virtual Partner Partner { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swagger error: Conflicting schemaIds: Duplicate schemaIds detected for types A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071513/swagger-error-conflicting-schemaids-duplicate-schemaids-detected-for-types-a-a)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Try this John: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1607#issuecomment-607170559
helped me.

I can understand what is happening; i have several enums with 'Status' or 'Type'.
Using
`options.CustomSchemaIds( type => type.ToString() );`
solved this.

Comment: This works. @John Bowyer put breakpoint into options.CustomSchemaIds( type => {  type.ToString(); // breakpoint } ); to see what types come into this lambda. Or try this code options.CustomSchemaIds( type => type.ToString() + type.GetHashCode() );

Comment: using `type.FullName` is also a good way to do this...

Comment: This helped me. In a medium-large project, there were same named enum definitions in various classes. Enum type's string representation solved the schema creation of swagger.

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7911 there are still issues with the + sign. `c.CustomSchemaIds(s => s.FullName.Replace("+", "."));` avoids that issue

Comment: Does fullname cause https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A3_2017-Sensitive_Data_Exposure.html?

Answer (score 100):

The only change needed is in your `Startup.cs` inside the method `ConfigureServices`.

You should add the following:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the `AddSwaggerGen` mention helped a lot. My problem is resolved.

Comment: This worked for me. Still trying to understand why it is choking with my code, though. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I've been using `options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());` and `options.CustomSchemaIds(type => $"{type.Name}_{System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "")}")` to create uniqueness on schema names. Both results in longer schema names which I hate.

Here's a different approach which track the name repetition, which I prefer.

Helper class:

```
internal static class SwashbuckleSchemaHelper
{
   private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> _schemaNameRepetition = new Dictionary<string, int>();

   public static string GetSchemaId(Type type)
   {
      string id = type.Name;

      if (!_schemaNameRepetition.ContainsKey(id))
          _schemaNameRepetition.Add(id, 0);

      int count = (_schemaNameRepetition[id] + 1);
      _schemaNameRepetition[id] = count;

      return type.Name + (count > 1 ? count.ToString() : "");
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
options.CustomSchemaIds(type => SwashbuckleSchemaHelper.GetSchemaId(type));
```

This would result as below, if the class name was duplicated.

- Invoice
- LineItem
- Status
- Status2

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly more flexible solution

```cs
options.CustomSchemaIds(type => SwashbuckleSchemaHelper.GetSchemaId(type));
```

**Helper**

```cs
public static class SwashbuckleSchemaHelper
{
    private static readonly string _rootNamespace;
    private static readonly string _dtoFolder = "Dtos";

    static SwashbuckleSchemaHelper()
    {
        _rootNamespace = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.Name);
    }

    private static string GetRelativeNamespace(string typeNamespace)
    {
        if (!typeNamespace.StartsWith(_rootNamespace))
        {
            return typeNamespace;
        }

        var relativenamespace = typeNamespace.Substring(_rootNamespace.Length + _dtoFolder.Length + 1).TrimStart('.');
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(relativenamespace))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return $"{relativenamespace}.";
    }

    public static string GetSchemaId(Type type)
    {
        var schemaBase = $"{GetRelativeNamespace(type.Namespace)}{type.Name}";

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            string? schemaGeneric;
            if (type.GenericTypeArguments.Length > 0)
            {
                var firstItem = type.GenericTypeArguments.First();
                schemaGeneric = $"<{GetRelativeNamespace(firstItem.Namespace)}{firstItem.Name}>";
            }
            else
            {
                schemaGeneric = $"<{Guid.NewGuid()}>";
            }

            return $"{schemaBase}{schemaGeneric}";
        }

        return $"{schemaBase}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a slightly nicer type name I came up with this:

```cs
  public class SwashbuckleSchemaHelper
  {
      private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _schemaNameRepetition = new();

      // borrowed from https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/95cb4d370e08e54eb04cf14e7e6388ca974a686e/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SchemaGenerator/SchemaGeneratorOptions.cs#L44
      private string DefaultSchemaIdSelector(Type modelType)
      {
          if (!modelType.IsConstructedGenericType) return modelType.Name.Replace("[]", "Array");

          var prefix = modelType.GetGenericArguments()
              .Select(genericArg => DefaultSchemaIdSelector(genericArg))
              .Aggregate((previous, current) => previous + current);

          return prefix + modelType.Name.Split('`').First();
      }

      public string GetSchemaId(Type modelType)
      {
          string id = DefaultSchemaIdSelector(modelType);

          if (!_schemaNameRepetition.ContainsKey(id))
              _schemaNameRepetition.Add(id, 0);

          int count = _schemaNameRepetition[id] + 1;
          _schemaNameRepetition[id] = count;

          return $"{id}{(count > 1 ? count.ToString() : "")}";
      }
  }
```

Usage looks like this:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    var schemaHelper = new SwashbuckleSchemaHelper();
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => schemaHelper.GetSchemaId(type));
});
```

More details here:

https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2022/08/31/swashbuckle-schemaid-already-used

Answer (score 1):

The best way as far as I see to handle this is to provide `CustomSchemaIds` method, however this means that the default schema selector will no longer run which means you lose support for generics.

The best way I found to deal with this was to simply copy the implementation of `DefaultSchemaIdSelector`, then run that before/after my custom logic (which adds a prefix to schemaId based on namespace).

DefaultSchemaIdSelector:

```cs
private static string DefaultSchemaIdSelector(Type modelType)
{
    if (!modelType.IsConstructedGenericType)
    {
        return modelType.Name.Replace("[]", "Array");
    }

    var prefix = modelType.GetGenericArguments()
        .Select(DefaultSchemaIdSelector)
        .Aggregate((previous, current) => previous + current);

    return $"{prefix}{modelType.Name.Split('`').First()}";
}
```

Then in SwaggerGen:

```cs
c.CustomSchemaIds(type =>
{
    var schemaId = DefaultSchemaIdSelector(type);

    // Some namespace checking
    var prefix = ".....";

    return $"{prefix}.{schemaId}";
});
```

**Older answer:** (might still be relevant)

After doing some research it seems like the way to go is to use the `FriendlyId` extension method to generate custom schema id's... but I couldn't find that method in any of the recent versions of Swashbuckle/Swagger so I just ended up copying the implementation from the old `Swashbuckle.Core` package to my project and refactoring it a bit:

```cs
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static string FriendlyId(this Type type, bool fullyQualified = false)
    {
        var typeName = fullyQualified
            ? type.FullNameSansTypeParameters().Replace("+", ".")
            : type.Name;

        if (!type.IsGenericType)
        {
            return typeName;
        }

        var genericArgumentIds = type.GetGenericArguments()
            .Select(t => FriendlyId(t, fullyQualified))
            .ToArray();

        return new StringBuilder(typeName)
            .Replace($"`{genericArgumentIds.Length}", string.Empty)
            .Append($"[{string.Join(",", genericArgumentIds).TrimEnd(',')}]")
            .ToString();
    }

    public static string FullNameSansTypeParameters(this Type type)
    {
        var fullName = type.FullName;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
        {
            fullName = type.Name;
        }

        var chopIndex = fullName.IndexOf("[[", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        return (chopIndex == -1) ? fullName : fullName[..chopIndex];
    }
}
```

Usage in AddSwaggerGen method:

```cs
c.CustomSchemaIds(t => t.FriendlyId(true));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my version of `SwashbuckleSchemaHelper`

```
public static class SwashbuckleSchemaHelper
{
    public static string GetSchemaId(Type type)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(type.Namespace);
        sb.Append('.');
        sb.Append(type.Name);

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            sb.Append('<');

            var arguments = type.GenericTypeArguments
                .Select(GetSchemaId)
                .ToArray();

            sb.Append(string.Join(',', arguments));

            sb.Append('>');
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).