# Exclude specific properties of a class property from another class to avoid circular reference

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

I have a freezing issue with Swashbuckle Swagger UI on some of our endpoints. This looks to be an issue with circular references. After some research, I still couldn't find a fix.

I found this SO question which is similar to my issue although mine isn't crashing, just freezing - [Swagger crashes with circular model references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705270/swagger-crashes-with-circular-model-references).

To illustrate:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // ...some other properties, up to 100 columns in some cases
    public virtual List<ObjectB> Foo { get; set; }

}

public class ObjectB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RefId { get; set; }
    // ...some other properties, up to 100 columns in some cases
    public virtual ObjectA RefObj { get; set; }
}
```

Removing the properties in either of the above classes isn't an option as it is required to expose all the linked entities. I also don't want to create `ObjectBsObjectA` custom class which would contain only the properties without the circular reference as it would mean I have to make one for every circular reference for `ObjectB`.

My idea is that to exlude, or `null` out, `ObjectA.Foo`'s `ObjectA` property when serializing `ObjectA`:

```
ObjectA {
 Id: 'objAId',
 //... other properties
 Foo: [
   {
     Id: 'someObjectBId',
     RefId: 'objAId',
     //... other properties of ObjectB
     RefObj: null
   }
 ]
}
```

I tried searching but I couldn't find anything on the web. I also tried `protected`, `protected internal` but these totally excludes all the properties even in the main class.

Probably something like a filter attribute or something? like:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // ...some other properties, up to 100 columns in some cases
    [DoNotInclude("RefObj")]
    public virtual List<ObjectB> Foo { get; set; }

}

public class ObjectB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RefId { get; set; }
    // ...some other properties, up to 100 columns in some cases
    [DoNotInclude("Foo")]
    public virtual ObjectA RefObj { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179310/6895130

Answer (score 3):

While you can exclude properties from serialization with corresponding attributes ([`JsonIgnoreAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=net-6.0) for `System.Text.Json` and one with the same name for [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm), pick correct one based on what is used for serialization, `System.Text.Json` being default one nowadays):

```cs
public class ObjectB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RefId { get; set; }
    // ...some other properties, up to 100 columns in some cases
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ObjectA RefObj { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that you are trying to reuse your EF entities to expose as API models - in general case I recommend not to do this. Create special classes to use as inbound and outbound models ([DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)'s) and map them from and to the db entites (you can use one of the existing mapper libraries to reduce amount of code, [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster), [mapperly](https://github.com/riok/mapperly) and others).

Comment: HI. Thanks for answering. However, `[JsonIgnore]` will totally ignore the `RefObj` property if `RefObj` in your example. What I wanted was to only ignore `ObjectB.RefObj.Foo`.

Comment: @GeomanYabes you can also try playing with serializer settings for handling cycles ([`Newtonsoft`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853407/json-net-not-respecting-preservereferenceshandling-on-deserialization), [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0))